# suggestions to allow trials for multiple recovery methods against corrupted media

Tags: backup

looking to be sure I can recover data from a corrupted sd card.  I don't want any one recovery method to stop me from being able to recover the data.  Due to this, I am looking to bit level backup the sd card.  If one fails I should be able to recover the card and try again.

However, I am a bit lost as to which product actually does that level of a backup these days. No one seems to use the old terms for descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/ fits the bill I guess.

Note that *any* decent file recovery tool can do this too, most times with the free demo version even. Examples ReclaiMe, DMDE, R-Studio.

Linux: ddrescue, example/guide: https://www.recoveryforce.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=245